# React / React Spring List Animate Out Not Working

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I'm experimenting with [`react-spring`](https://github.com/drcmda/react-spring) trying to apply animations on a list of components on mount/unmount using the `<Transition>` component. The animation happens as expected on mount but doesn't happen at all on unmount–the removed components appear to immediately unmount without animation.

I suspect I'm misunderstanding how `keys` work as it seems to be the only thing that differs in my code versus the examples—I'm using the `id` property from each object an array. My assumption is that it's the same as React's built-in `key` used for lists of components, just passed all at once. I've tried passing the data array using `Transition`'s `items` argument and setting `key` to be a function, but it just malfunctions in a different way.

I set up a simple demo here, where I made a list and set a timeout to remove the first item after 3 seconds—here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { animated, config, Transition } from "react-spring";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "This is item 1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: "This is item 2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: "This is item 3"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        items: items.slice(1)
      });
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          <Transition
            native
            keys={items.map(item => item.id)}
            config={config.slow}
            from={{ opacity: 0 }}
            to={{ opacity: 1 }}
          >
            {items.map(item => styles => {
              return <animated.li style={styles}>{item.text}</animated.li>;
            })}
          </Transition>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And I've it running on a CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r5n8v3x85q

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following code. You were missing the "leave" property on the Transition component. Also you can pass in "transition" for the properties in the Transition component, it will give you much nicer looking animations.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { animated, config, Transition } from "react-spring";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "This is item 1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: "This is item 2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: "This is item 3"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        items: items.slice(1)
      });
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({items: []})}>Remove List items</button> 
        <ul>
          <Transition
            native
            keys={items.map(item => item.id)}
            config={config.slow}
            from={{ opacity: 0, transition: "opacity .25s ease"  }}
            to={{ opacity: 1, transition: "opacity .25s ease"  }}
            leave={{ opacity: 0, transition: "opacity .25s ease" }}
          >
            {items.map(item => styles => {
              return <animated.li style={styles}>{item.text}</animated.li>;
            })}
          </Transition>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Totally missed that `leave` property.

So I got an updated Sandbox and the transitions seem to work, but the components remain in the DOM after they fade out, but I would expect them to unmount. Do you know what's going on there?

https://codesandbox.io/s/k0n36omqr

Comment: 1 thing to try: 1. Try this code in an actual running app, (create-react-app) or something else instead of codesandbox. I noticed as well that it was hit and miss in codesandbox, it would work sometimes and not other times.